# MATLAB: Efficient way to calculate a covariance matrix from this data

Tags: matlab, covariance

I have a data file in which there are N=428 subjects each answering the same 8 questions. It looks like this:

```
 question subject  score    
    1        1       42         
    2        1       12
    3        1       13
    4        1       43
    5        1       22
    6        1       43 
    7        1       54
    8        1       66
    1        2       41
    2        2       11
   ...      ...     ...
```

I want to calculate and store a covariance matrix reflecting the scores of each subject.

So cell (1,1) has subject 1's variance. then cells (1,2) and (2,1) would both have the same value, i.e. the covariance between subject 1 and subject 2. Although in the table above you can't see all of subject 2's data, it looks like they would have some positive covariance with subject 1.

*n* choose *k* unique covariances must be calculated, which I work out to be 91378 total.

How can I efficiently achieve this?

EDIT: Using the code from @GameOfThrows I was able to get a working version going using a loop:

```
crowd_cov = NaN(428,428);

for i = 1:length(allpairs)
    Z = cov(score(indexSub1(i,1):indexSub1(i,2)),score(indexSub2(i,1):indexSub2(i,2)));
    first = allpairs(i,1);
    second = allpairs(i,2);
    crowd_cov(first,first) = Z(1,1);
    crowd_cov(second,second) = Z(2,2);
    crowd_cov(first,second) = Z(1,2);
    crowd_cov(second,first) = Z(2,1);
end
```

I'm happy with this, although I would still welcome an explanation of how I could have coded this more efficiently.

Comment: Find and store the average of each column and then take the squared difference between each entry and the respective column's average. Also bear in mind that in your covariance matrix, covariance ( i,j) = covariance(j,i)

Comment: You suggest I take the average of all 8×428 = 3424 scores, which is 32.64. Then I take for row one 42-32.64 and square that, and do the same for all rows. How do I proceed from that point?

Comment: I am slightly confused, why not use Matlab covariance function (cov(A,B)) to do the covariance for each subject?

Comment: I intend to do that, but I'm wondering how best to apply that function given the setup of my data matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you want the co-variance, which tells me that you have two random variables, say score of subject 1 and score of subject 2, let's for now hope that the column Questions will not play a big part in this, but if number of Questions are the same for each subject, then it will hugely increase the efficiency of your program (because it allows fast indexing).

```
allpairs = combnk(1:max(subject),2) %// all possible combinations of subjects starting from subject 1 to subject N and the 2 means you want pairs.
```

Now note that this does not have repetitions, so sub 1 vs sub 2 only happens once, sub 2 vs sub 1 does not exist.

Now you want to do matlab cov to each pair (you need to index correctly to the score). This is where if you have the same number of questions, it will save you a lot of time, say 8 questions for each subject:

```
indexSub1 = [(allpairs(:,1)*8 -7),(allpairs(:,1)*8)]
indexSub2 = [(allpairs(:,2)*8 -7),(allpairs(:,2)*8)]
```

now you have all your correct indexes, you can use cov; as a function, apply it to every 8 elements of

```
cov(score(indexSub1),score(indexSub2)).
```

If the number of questions are not the same, then you might have to use find to index correctly, this would slow your program down a bit.

At the end you can convert your matrix to a cell and use cellfun to apply cov, or you can use a loop for simpler representations(am I suggesting a loop? No).

EDIT:

To clarify, what I am suggesting is that you have your indexSub1 and indexSub2, you can convert these into 91378*2 cells, where each cell consists of 8 scores. This will allow you to use Matlab's cellfun (where a function is applied to each cell). This will drastically increase your speed.

Comment: The number of questions is the same for every subject - it's 8. When I run this code I get the error message "Undefined function 'score' for input arguments of type 'double'." Is score meant to be something else?

Comment: I realise now that score should be a vector of scores. When I do that the code works, although it produces only a single 2x2 covariance matrix. Would you be able to explain a bit more what you mean by "apply it to every 8 elements of"?

Comment: @user1205901 the Matlab cov function returns a 2x2 covar matrix if the size of both random variables are the same, in your case, if all of them has 8 questions, then you will get a 2x2 covariance matrix for each pair.

Comment: Also, when I say apply it to every 8 element, what I really meant was that you can do this entire process without using a for loop. Consider this: If I take every 8 scores from indexSub1 and indexSub2 (which refers to 1 pair) and put them into a cell, I should have 91378 * 2 cells, where each cell consists of 8 scores. I can now use cellfun to apply the cov function to each cell (which is a parallel process that is so much faster than a loop).